# How to cache properly multiple versions of page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I have three different methods in 3 controllers, one is responsible for search, second for PartialView (sidebar, category list) and the method responsible for the view itself. Does anyone know how to cache properly, in which controller and according to which parameters(VaryByParam, VaryByHeader)?

```
1)
        [ChildActionOnly]
        // [OutputCache(Duration = 20, VaryByParam ="*")]
        public ActionResult KatList()
        {
            return PartialView(KatModelFactory.NewKatModel(Ctx, Session, false));
        }

2)
        [HttpPost]
        //[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache30Min", VaryByParam = "*")]
        public ActionResult Search(HeaderModel model)
        {
            //omitted
        }



 3)     [HttpGet]
        //[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache30Min", VaryByParam="*")]
        public ActionResult Category(string id)
        {
            return View(KatModelFactory.NewKatModelDetail(Ctx, Session, id));
        }
```